# Read SQLite table in activity onCreate

Tags: android, android-sqlite

In my app I want to initialize some data stored in a SQLite database.

But it turns out the SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate method is not called when I read my database (it is when I write into my database).
My app crash when I read the db for a table that does not exist (it does not crash if I create the table before). I could catch the exception but does not seem very clean to me.

Is it the normal behavior regarding SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate method or am I missing something?

Here is the initialisation function called in activity OnCreate()

```
    private void InitializeDbPlayerList() {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor cursorPlayers;
    DbPlayerData dbPlayerData;

    db = mGameDbHelper.getReadableDatabase ();
    // The following line crash the app if PLAYER_TABLE_NAME does not exist
    cursorPlayers=db.query(GameDatabaseOpenHelper.PLAYER_TABLE_NAME,
            GameDatabaseOpenHelper.player_columns, null, new String[] {}, null, null,
            null);      
    cursorPlayers.moveToFirst();
    for(int j=0;j<cursorPlayers.getCount();j++)
    {
        dbPlayerData = new DbPlayerData(cursorPlayers.getString(0),cursorPlayers.getFloat(1),cursorPlayers.getFloat(2),
                cursorPlayers.getInt(3),cursorPlayers.getInt(4));
        mDbPlayerList .add(dbPlayerData);
    }
}
```

Thx
Fabien

Comment: `the SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate method is not called when I read my database (it is when I write into my database).` It **shouldn't**. The `onCreate()` method is only called upon the object instancing. `My app crash when I read the db for a table that does not exist (it does not crash if I create the table before)` Is it something that makes you wonder? I find it quite **logical**.

Comment: I agree the fact that the onCreate function is called makes sense. But I'm surprise I cannot do something as simple as reading the database without crashing the app.
Must I check if the table exists each time I read the db? This is what does not make much sense to me.
If I was not using the SQLite I would always create the Table at init if they do not exist and then would never check the existence again. So it is the whole SQLiteOpenHelp oncreate callback process logic that I don't really get.

Comment: So what do you disagree?

Comment: Actually I have difficulties to understand upon which event the onCreate function is called.
But eventually my problem comes from the fact that I added a new table to my db and it seems due to that I had to delete the whole db so that it is correctly created from scratch.
Now I don't have anymore problem.

Thx for the help

Comment: It's called when you **instance** the DataBase Helper object in the calling Activity (something like `DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper();`). And that's the only call (exception: if the database has been promoted to a higher version, then it's called in the `onUpgrade()` method)

Comment: Thx that's what I was thinking.
But apparently if you create a new table in your app onCreate is not called upon DataBaseHelper creation probably because database was already created for former table (which is logical since android does not there is a new table). 
I think that was my problem.

Comment: If you added a new table, then the db structure changed. So, you have to set the **DATABASE_VERSION** constant to a higher number. This will make the `onUpgrade()` method fire, to create the new table/s, then call the `onCreate()` method to recreate the "old" table/s as well.